Setting a PHP Cookie within an AJAX Call
This is not a duplicate question: how can set cookie with Ajax/jQuery?
Either way the cookie does change, but the output of the following, doesn't change without a refresh.
<?php echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE['country']; ?>

I'm pretty new to AJAX so I'm struggling a little with my functionality for my WordPress site.
I have a dropdown list of countries and when a user selects a different country, I would like to update the cookie (which is already set) and therefore the page should load the new cookie without reloading the page.
At the moment I have to hit refresh for this to show the correct country code from using the code below, whereas I'd have hoped AJAX would do this without refreshing the page:
<?php echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE['country']; ?>

My code is below, but I'm sure some of it may not be needed or is wrong.
JS
$('.single-country-select').on("change", function (e) {
    var country_code_value = $('.single-country-select').val();
    var sendData = {
        action: 'country_change_ajax_function',
        country_code_value: country_code_value
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxadminurl.ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: sendData,
        dataType: 'html',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            // SET COOKIE HERE??
        }
    });
});

functions.php
function country_change_ajax_function() {
    $country_code_value = $_POST['country_code_value'];
    setcookie('country', $country_code_value, time() + (86400 * 30), '/');
    exit;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_country_change_ajax_function', 'country_change_ajax_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_country_change_ajax_function', 'country_change_ajax_function');

I've also got some code at the top of my header that sets the cookie automatically:
if(!isset($_COOKIE['country'])) {
    $get_user_country_code = simplexml_load_file("http://www.geoplugin.net/xml.gp?ip=".getRealIpAddr());
    if ($get_user_country_code === false) {
        $user_country_code = 'GB';
        setcookie('country', 'GB', time() + (86400 * 30), '/');
    } else {
        $user_country_code = $get_user_country_code->geoplugin_countryCode;
        setcookie('country', $user_country_code, time() + (86400 * 30), '/');
    }
}

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Your browser isn’t receiving html to parse and display when you get an Ajax response.  So I would suggest you update the “Value is” part using JavaScript in the success function, and reading the new cookie value from document.cookie.

@James As suggested I used:
success: function(data) {
document.cookie = 'country='+country_code_value+'; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2025 12:00:00 UTC; path=/';
}
It does change the Cookie, but I still need to refresh the page for the $_COOKIE['country'] to show it's been changed. I need it to do it without the refresh.
Any ideas? Thanks!

No, I mean use Javascript to update the page.  <?php echo "<div id='updateMe'>Value is: " . $_COOKIE['country'] . "</div>"; > and then document.querySelector('#updateMe').innerText = "Value is: " + getCookie("country") in the success function, where getCookie is defined here
